# Most important results for Shalika germs

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, lie-algebras

This is more of a general question, but what do you think are the most important results for Shalika germs if you were giving a presentation? You can assume the target audience to be 2nd-3rd year graduate students who have seen a little orbital integrals and the general idea before, together with the computation for $GL_2$.

I was thinking of their existence, homogeneity and linear independence, as proved in Kottwitz's article http://groups.claymath.org/library/proceedings/cmip04.pdf#page=405 
and some computations mainly of the Shalika germs of the higher orbital integrals (highest and second highest) on $GL_n$. Is there some other easy computation I could do on board? Do you think this can be reasonably covered in 90 minutes? Also, is Kottwitz's presentation the most direct way to go about all this? What are important results on Shalika germs I could put into the presentation that I haven't mentioned?